# Set Months and Day Ranges for SelectDateWidget in Django

Tags: python, django, date, django-forms

I have a SelectDateWidget in a Django form that should only allow users to select dates from a certain number of years ago. How do I limit the months and days in the widget? For example, a user born in the last possible year should not be able to select January 1 when the current date is January 28. Similarly, someone born in the most recent possible year should not be allowed to select February 1 when the current date is January 28.

Here is my form:

```
class Form(forms.Form):
    birthday = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(empty_label=('Year', 'Month', 'Day'), years=range(datetime.date.today().year-22, datetime.date.today().year - 15)))
```

How do I set the months and days allowed in the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what are the rules for your widget, but you could always use form constructor to create the field dynamically:

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user:
            # calculate the list of years based on user's information and the rules you have
            # e.g. years = range(2010, 2016)
            self.fields['birthday'] = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(empty_label=('Year', 'Month', 'Day'), 
                                                      years=years))
```

Then in your views you do:

```
def views(request):
    form = FooForm(request.POST or None, user=request.user)
```